# Are students from Government Aided schools eligible for the 7.5% reservation in NEET?

Tags: india, education, students

TamilNadu government recently [passed a bill](https://www.theweek.in/news/india/2020/10/29/neet-quota-bill-tn-govt-passes-order-for-75-reservation-for-govt-school-students.html) that provides a 7.5% reservation for government school students in the [NEET medical entrance exam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Eligibility_cum_Entrance_Test_(Undergraduate)). In TamilNadu, usually government and aided schools are treated in the same manner while concerning government schemes e.g)Nutrion meals, laptops schemes, etc...

My question is that, Is this reservation applicable for students studying in Government Aided schools too? I couldn't find any information related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing, students studying in Government Aided schools are not eligible for the 7.5% percent reservation in NEET exams.

Petitions have been filed in courts challenging this.

**References**:

1. [Why exclude govt-aided students from 7.5% quota? | Indian Express](https://www.newindianexpress.com/cities/chennai/2020/dec/09/why-exclude-govt-aided-students-from-75-quota-2233649.html)
2. [Plea challenges exclusion of government-aided school students from 7.5% medical admission quota | The Hindu](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/tamil-nadu/plea-challenges-exclusion-of-government-aided-school-students-from-75-medical-admission-quota/article33283982.ece)